# Reviewing my c++ multidimensional array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In my main function I'm creating an array:

`char arr[0x10000][9];`

In another class `B` I would like to have a pointer to this array:

```
typedef char memory[0x10000][9];

class B{
   public:
      B(memory* mem);
   private:
   memory* _mem;
}
```

and the implementation

```
B::B(memory* mem){
   this->_mem = mem;
}
```

And the main function:

```
....
char arr[0x10000][9];   
arr[0][0] = 7; 
arr[0][1] = 7;
// and so on...
B* b = new B(&arr, true);
...
```

Unfortunately, I can only access `_mem[0][0]` correctly, if I access `_mem[0][1]`, then I'm getting some random value, but not the one that I set in the main method.

Comment: Who owns that pointer (= it is responsible to free that memory?) Are your objects copied (by value)? Is ownership transferred?

Comment: [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/3309790)

Comment: The main function "owns" the array, and I want to pass it by reference to my B class, which will only read from that array. I edited my question to make it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(*_mem)[0][1];` to get the value. you have pointer to double dimensional array as data member